# geant4 on Ubuntu

Tags: server

I install geant4 on Ubuntu 18.04 
there is a problem when i copy the geant4 environment variables to system environment variables folder. What can I do? [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iix7y.jpg)

Comment: You can edit your post and copy, paste and format the text in your image. Posting images of text is not the way.

Comment: "copy the geant4 environment variables to system environment variables folder" is too vague - tell us exactly what commands you wrote

Comment: I try.. Set environment variables in .bashrc .. By
source /home/user/Geant4/geant4.10.02.p02-install/bin/geant4.sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Geant4 10.4 is a powerful complex application for the fields of physics, mathematics, and engineering.  Perhaps you should review the installation procedure carefully [here](https://ruyetao.com/ubuntu_geant4/) specific to Ubuntu 18.04 and verify dependencies etc.

The errors you posted clearly indicate the expected directory structure has not been built.

Comment: Thank you but how can I change within the terminal  to ( 
geant4_envbindirg ="/usr/local/Geant4/bin")?